# Can a DOM element have an attribute whose value is an arbitrary object (not a string)?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes

I'd like to do something like this:

```
var elem = document.createElement("input");
elem.setAttribute("my-attribute", myObject);
document.getElementById("parent").appendChild(elem);
```

Later I will need to fetch `myObject` when performing some actions on this (and similar) element(s).

Note: I need this as an attribute (and not, for example, as a member of the element object, as in `elem.myAttribute = myObject`), as for some elements the value is a string which is hard-coded into the HTML of the page. What I need is the ability to set this attribute programmatically for other elements, and to use values which are not always plain strings.

I tried this and it worked in my browser (Firefox 14), but I need to know if this works cross-browser, and also if I'll be able to fetch the values of such attributes using jQuery if I decide to use jQuery in my page later on.

Comment: You can use the data attribute in jquery to do this (http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: @Magrangs: thanks, but my question is about setting attributes - see the Note. Also, it will be good if this is jQuery-compatible, but I am looking for a plain JavaScript solution.

Comment: Can still do this by adding it as an attribute and retrieving it using the data api e.g. <p data-config="{hello: 'this is a test'}">lalala></p>

Comment: (http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/)

Comment: Note: the object will have to be stringified (JSON.stringify()) as mentioned below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - attributes by definition store string values. The obvious approach is to store the object as a property but you say that's not suitable.

Either:

1) Use jQuery's data API (since it does not literally log the data on the element, so you can store whatever you want, not only strings)

2) Stringify the object and append that to the element as an HTML5 data attribute.

```
var elem = document.querySelector('p'),
    obj = {foo: 'bar'};
elem.setAttribute('data-myObj', JSON.stringify(obj));
/* ...then, later... */
var data = JSON.parse(elem.getAttribute('data-myObj'));
```

Note, though, that, because we're dealing with JSON, you will not be able to store methods as part of this object. They will be stripped out by `JSON.stringify()`.

Finally, using attributes means you'll muddy your HTML since they show up in any HTML dumps (unlike properties) but this is purely a cosmetic weakness.

Comment: This is exactly the approach we have taken (however we use the jquery data api for retrieval), works well for us.

Comment: A bit disappointing that only strings are supported, but as I can stringify my objects it works (and there's no need for any jQuery or any special API). In some cases I might need methods; I think I won't use plain JSON, but rather I'll stringify the object myself, using names for the methods, and then I'll decode it using `eval`.

Comment: It's not so much a question support as one of definition. Attributes - in HTMl, XML, whatever - are strings. It wouldn't make any sense to be able to store complex data such as objects in them, because this would not be manifestable visually, e.g. when you run `innerHTML`. Don't forget eval() is evil :) There's nothing stopping you using an approach like jQuery's (data not physically stored on the elements) but recreated to avoid jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the data attribute in jquery to do this (http://api.jquery.com/data/)

You can use html 5 data attributes:
http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

And these can be retrieved using the jquery data api.

These will have to be stringifed however

"As of jQuery 1.4.3 HTML 5 data- attributes will be automatically pulled in to jQuery's data object"

Comment: "These will have to be stringifed however" probably should have made it clearer however - trying to do two things at once!

Comment: Apologies - comment removed. Short attention span. +1 for good measure.